# Invalidation of datasource PagedList Android

Tags: android, android-paging

I need some insight on invalidation of `datasource` in a `PagedList`, like how it behaves and what should be done to attach a new `datasource`/`PagedList`.

What I believe is that we cannot attach a new `datasource`, so do we need to attach a new `PagedList` to the `recyclerView`? If so how to make the new `PagedList` fetch the same items which I was last scrolling on.So that there is no flicker in the screen. As of now when a new `PagedList` is emitted(I am using `RxPagedListBuilder`), the data on the screen changes.

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource) ^F `Updating Paged Data`

Comment: According to the doc, 
`If you have more granular update signals, such as a network API signaling an update to a single item in the list, it's recommended to load data from network into memory. Then present that data to the PagedList via a DataSource that wraps an in-memory snapshot. Each time the in-memory copy changes, invalidate the previous DataSource, and a new one wrapping the new state of the snapshot can be created.`
1. So do we need not to create a new `PagedList`?
2. If we do, then how to make the `PagedList` fetch the same "_page_" it was earlier at.

Comment: they say to use `invalidate()` method when the content changes in any way